# How to set the value of a drop down menu via the URL

Tags: html, forms, url

recently I have been trying to effectively parse values to a `<selection>` tag. For example, I have been trying:

```
/index.html?exampleId=examplevalue
```

Yet, this doesn't seem to be working. For added context, here is an example that replicates the structure of my `<selection>` tag:

```
        <form method="GET">
            <select id="CategorySelect" name="CategorySelect">
                <option value="default">Select an Option</option>
                <option value="dogs">Dogs</option>
                <option value="cats">Cats</option>
                <option value="horses">Horses</option>
                <option value="otheranimals">Other animals</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this you submit  the form either through js or by clicking a submit element and the in the php you check the value

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to pre-fill form inputs based on the query string of the URL.

If so, first you need to parse the query String.

In this example I assign the result of an Immediately Invoked Function Expression to a variable named `$_GET` (after the variable with the same in PHP used to store the same information).

Inside the IIFE I split the query string by all occurences of `?` or `&`, then loop through the results and split any non-falsey items by `=`. I assign the results of the final split to an object.

Finally return that object to the `$_GET` variable.

```js
var $_GET = (function(s,o,a) {
    return s.split(/\?|\&/g).forEach(function(i){i&&(a = i.split('='))&&(o[a[0]] = a[1]);}), o;
    // split the query by ? or &; iterate the results; split each item by =; assign the result; return the object
})(location.search,{},[]);
```

Next you need to find elements with the correct names and set the values. So iterate the query object we just made; find all elements that have the correct name; iterate the elements' test the elements tag names so we know how to properly set the value.

This method will work even if there are multiple forms with similar elements on the same page.

```js
// Loop through $_GET; Get a list of all nodes, and the value to set
for(var i in $_GET) (function(nodelist, value){
    // Loop through the nodelist
    for(var i in Object.keys(nodelist)) (function(el){
        // If the element is an input element, set it's value
        if(/input/i.test(el.tagName)) el.value = value;
        // If the element is a select element, set the default option
        if(/select/i.test(el.tagName)) el.querySelector('[value="'+value+'"]').selected = true;
    })(nodelist[i]);
})(document.querySelectorAll('[name="'+i+'"]'), $_GET[i]);
```

Expand and run the following demo to see it in action.

```js
var $_GET = (function(s,o,a) {
    return s.split(/\?|\&/g).forEach(function(i){i&&(a = i.split('='))&&(o[a[0]] = a[1]);}), o;
    // split the query by ? or &; split each item by =; assign the result; return the object
})("?fruit=banana&greeting=evening",{},[]); 
//  ^^ For demo purposes only, use location.search instead.

// Loop through $_GET; Get a list of all nodes, and the value to set
for(var i in $_GET) (function(nodelist, value){
    // Loop through the nodelist
    for(var i in Object.keys(nodelist)) (function(el){
        // If the element is an input element, set it's value
        if(/input/i.test(el.tagName)) el.value = value;
        // If the element is a select element, set the default option
        if(/select/i.test(el.tagName)) el.querySelector('[value="'+value+'"]').selected = true;
    })(nodelist[i]);
})(document.querySelectorAll('[name="'+i+'"]'), $_GET[i]);
```

```html
<form>
    <select name="fruit">
        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    </select>
    <select name="greeting">
        <option value="morning">Good Morning</option>
        <option value="afternoon">Good Afternoon</option>
        <option value="evening">Good Evening</option>
    </select>
</form>
<form>
    <select name="fruit">
        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    </select>
    <select name="greeting">
        <option value="morning">Good Morning</option>
        <option value="afternoon">Good Afternoon</option>
        <option value="evening">Good Evening</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the form you will receive the values in $_GET (or $_POST depending on form method)

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['CategorySelect'])){ // test if you have submitted something
   echo $_GET['CategorySelect'];
}
?>
<form method="GET">
    <select id="CategorySelect" name="CategorySelect">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="dogs">Dogs</option>
        <option value="cats">Cats</option>
        <option value="horses">Horses</option>
        <option value="otheranimals">Other animals</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"><!-- to be able to submit your form -->
</form>
```